# Vulkan + GLFW Fullscreen mode have "blink" when exit or switch to desktop

Tags: c++, glfw, vulkan

I use GLFW for Vulkan fullscreen mode and have "short blink" when exit from application or switch with alt-tab to desktop. It looks bad. Can I fix it?

Here you can see how it happens:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrPo0KeOPsg

Update:

```
glfwInit();
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Vulkan 12", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), nullptr);

VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo pipelineInfo = {};
    pipelineInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineInfo.stageCount = 2;
    pipelineInfo.pStages = shaderStages;
    pipelineInfo.pVertexInputState = &vertexInputInfo;
    pipelineInfo.pInputAssemblyState = &inputAssembly;
    pipelineInfo.pViewportState = &viewportState;
    pipelineInfo.pRasterizationState = &rasterizer;
    pipelineInfo.pMultisampleState = &multisampling;
    pipelineInfo.pColorBlendState = &colorBlending;
    pipelineInfo.layout = pipelineLayout;
    pipelineInfo.renderPass = renderPass;
    pipelineInfo.subpass = 0;
    pipelineInfo.basePipelineHandle = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
```

Loop:

```
void drawFrame() {
    uint32_t imageIndex;
    VkResult result = vkAcquireNextImageKHR(device, swapChain,  std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max(), imageAvailableSemaphore, VK_NULL_HANDLE, &imageIndex);

    if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR) {
        recreateSwapChain();
        return;
    }
    else if (result != VK_SUCCESS && result != VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to acquire swap chain image!");
    }

    VkSubmitInfo submitInfo = {};
    submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;

    VkSemaphore waitSemaphores[] = { imageAvailableSemaphore };
    VkPipelineStageFlags waitStages[] = { VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT };
    submitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pWaitSemaphores = waitSemaphores;
    submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask = waitStages;

    submitInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = &commandBuffers[imageIndex];

    VkSemaphore signalSemaphores[] = { renderFinishedSemaphore };
    submitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pSignalSemaphores = signalSemaphores;

    if (vkQueueSubmit(graphicsQueue, 1, &submitInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to submit draw command buffer!");
    }

    VkPresentInfoKHR presentInfo = {};
    presentInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR;

    presentInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
    presentInfo.pWaitSemaphores = signalSemaphores;

    VkSwapchainKHR swapChains[] = { swapChain };
    presentInfo.swapchainCount = 1;
    presentInfo.pSwapchains = swapChains;

    presentInfo.pImageIndices = &imageIndex;

    result = vkQueuePresentKHR(presentQueue, &presentInfo);

    if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR || result == VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR) {
        recreateSwapChain();
    }
    else if (result != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to present swap chain image!");
    }
}
```

https://vulkan-tutorial.com/

Update 2

Main loop:

```
void mainLoop() {
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {        
        glfwPollEvents();
        drawFrame();            
    }

// I add hiding window and blink after exit disappeared:    
ShowWindow(glfwGetWin32Window(window), SW_HIDE);


vkDeviceWaitIdle(device);
```

Comment: Can I see your main loop? Is it single threaded app? Do you call `vkDeviceIdle()` before destruction and before swapchain recreation? Do you have validation layers on (what do they say?)? ;; Is it Temporary or Borderless Fullscreen? Might just be ordinary video mode switch...

Comment: PS: What's the purpose of the vulkan tutorial link in the Q?

Comment: Update post. I think it single threated. Yes, vkDeviceWaitIdle called. Validation layers enabled and silent. It's Temporary fullscreen. When I add hiding window after exit from main loop - blink with exit application disappeared (now I see blink only if use alt-tab).  I added vulkan-tutorial.com because I get application thence, I only changed video mode to fullscreen.

Comment: Temporary fullscreen, but videomodes desktop and application the same - 1080p.

Comment: Does look like video mode swich then. I will try tommorow with my app. ;; I would recommend using `glfwSetWindowSizeCallback()` and
`glfwSetWindowRefreshCallback()`. In my experience without those two GLFW tends to miss some opportunities to repaint the window.

Comment: If the mode is the same then that is a Borderless Fullscreen (Follow http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#window_windowed_full_screen to achieve that). Your app is obviously making video mode switch though (the black screen) indicating it is Temporary (again follow the guide above if that is not your intention), Other thing I find curious is the slight blink before the resolution switch - my app does not do that for me.